# Permanent car camera secuity system?

Tags: car, security, camera

I am getting a new VW and from past experience I want to have a camera system built in the car for few reasons.

First, to record any possible accidents while driving and while I am not there. Second reason is to record the speed limit - and were thinking about a camera inside the cabine that record the driver and front dash.

I have few things that I wish to consider when getting this kit:

1. I am aware of the hundereds of options of the all differnet car DVRs and cameras. But most of them are powered from the 12V outlet. Are there kits out there that can be wired up to the main car's system, or have a backup battery that charges when the car is driving and can last for at least 12 hours?
2. Have 360 degree camera coverage around the car, and one inside the cabine to record the drive, windows, and dash (speed, when police polls you over, etc...) with sound.
3. Also, something that can be small enough so it will not attract attention of burglers and other curious type parties...

Any ideas, recommendations, and experiences (good and bad) are welcome.

Comment: One of these can *easily* be direct wired through the fuse box ... just separate out the wires and connect while hiding the wiring. As far as a battery backup, I'd first look at how much amperage draw a system would have. If small enough, you may not need to worry about it and run it off of the main battery. I've not used them before, but would bet there are ones which only turn on under certain situations, such as when the door opens for a period of time and then if the vehicle is running. I don't have any specific guidance for you, so leaving as a comment.

Comment: This question **is** on topic. The [FAQ](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states "Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and **their accessories**, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories."

Comment: Did I miss anything?

Comment: Nothing, just had 4 votes to close and it's on topic. You got notifications in you inbox because I was tweaking my comments and clearing the votes to close. You didn't ask about price you ask if it could be done and what some options were. Don't have time to post an full answer right now but will later with at least one option that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks. The more I was thinking about it, the more I was starting to think I will be needing to get all sepearte parts and do my own setup - which is going to be a mini-projecy. Will appreciate if there is something good already pre-made.

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop This is a product recommendation question, not a question about repairing anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about repairing anything.

Comment: Man, I like this question.  Even if it is off topic.

Comment: Not an answer, but your question 1 is a no brainer: options here are easy. You can wire anything up to permanent 12v. If it is high current draw, you can add an extra battery to make sure it will last overnight. Don't go for a kit for this piece.

Comment: That's true, but that wasn't the question. I'm was looking for a product solution, not a diy protect.